# Improving accuracy in Tess4j - best options

Tags: java, ocr, tess4j

I'm using **Tess4j** for text recognition from an image, but I'm having big problems with **recognition accuracy**.

I've already done some tests processing the image with the **openCV** tools, but although it helped, the problem is still not solved.

And I also tried transforming the image from png to svg to improve comprehensibility, using **ImageTracer** from jankovicsandras, but it didn't help with this problem.

Googling I found only one possibility: to **train the data** using the font present in the images I want to convert, but since it would take some time I'd like to discuss it with you first, if you have other ideas.

PS: it would take time because I don't have Linux and from Windows I would have to do the WSL.

Considering that the wiki says:

> *The existing model data provided has been trained on about 400000 textlines spanning about 4500 fonts*

so it's possible that it can't recognise this font (it's quite basic):

[image: font image]

Do you think it makes sense to train ocr for a specific font?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I tried (copy/paste) the image in VietOCR, which employs Tess4J, and got the correct results without any special image processing. The standard-issue `traineddata` pack seems to handle it well.